# Getting Syntax Error in TQDM Python FTP Program

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

When I try to run the Following Code It gives me a Syntax Error. Can Anybody Please tell me how to fix this Error. Thanks,

```
with tqdm(unit='blocks', unit_scale=True, leave=False, miniters=1, desc=f'Uploading {thumbnailname}......', total=filesize) as tqdm_instance:
    session.storbinary('STOR ' + thumbnailname, file, 2048,
                       callback=lambda sent: tqdm_instance.update(len(sent)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It works if you make a callback function that will update tqdm each iteration.

```
with tqdm(unit = 'b', unit_scale = True, leave = False, miniters = 1, desc = 'file name', total = filesize) as tqdm_instance:
    def tqdm_callback(data):
        # update progress bar and write out data
        tqdm_instance.update(len(data))
        raw_file.write(data)

        # check to see if download has completed
        if (raw_file.tell() == filesize):
            # close down the progress bar
            # prevents an extra ftp call which generates a timed out exception
            tqdm_instance.close()

    # make ftp data request
    ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR suppl/{raw_filename}", tqdm_callback)
```

from the python `methylprep` library https://github.com/FoxoTech/methylprep/blob/master/methylprep/download/geo.py#L152

However, I came here looking for more examples, because I think TQDM gets confused if FTP blocks have errors and have to be re-sent. In that case, the total blocks for the loop will change, and the loop might be ending before all blocks are done.